# Can send normal UDP packet with VB.net - But how do you send a WOL packet?

Tags: vb.net, network-programming, udp, wake-on-lan

I can send a packet with this:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim publisher As New Sockets.UdpClient(0)
Dim subscriber As New Sockets.UdpClient(2000)
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    publisher.Connect(TBTo.Text, TBPort.Text)
    Dim sendbytes() As Byte = ASCII.GetBytes("test")
    publisher.Send(sendbytes, sendbytes.Length)
End Sub
End Class
```

It works great and using WireShark I can see on Port 9 a UDP Packet being sent to my IP (which I type into the address/word box).

I understand for WOL (Which I DO have working, just want to make my own application for fun/experience) you need a MAC, will it just "adding a MAC" address to this make it a WOL packet or is it more complicated than that?

*NOTE:* I can see the difference in WOL and UDP packets in Wireshark and changing my IP to "MYIP". For example below is a WOL packet sent from a WOL application.

`40.000203000 MYIP 192.168.1.1 WOL 144 MagicPacket for Micro-St_21:94:b6 (44:8a:5b:21:94:b6)`

Compared to a normal UDP packet:

`69 12170.303276000 192.168.1.1 MYIP UDP 46 Source port: 57465  Destination port: 9`

EDIT:
I have played about A LOT with some examples but they are not the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do it after a few hours. If anyone else is stuck, here is how I did it:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim MacAddress As String = "YOUR MAC ADDRESS HERE"
    Dim myAddress As String = "YOURIP HERE"
    Dim udpClient As New System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient

    Dim buf(101) As Char

    Dim sendBytes As [Byte]() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(buf)

    For x As Integer = 0 To 5

        sendBytes(x) = CByte("&HFF")

    Next

    Dim i As Integer = 6

    For x As Integer = 1 To 16

        sendBytes(i) = CByte("&H" + MacAddress.Substring(0, 2))

        sendBytes(i + 1) = CByte("&H" + MacAddress.Substring(2, 2))

        sendBytes(i + 2) = CByte("&H" + MacAddress.Substring(4, 2))

        sendBytes(i + 3) = CByte("&H" + MacAddress.Substring(6, 2))

        sendBytes(i + 4) = CByte("&H" + MacAddress.Substring(8, 2))

        sendBytes(i + 5) = CByte("&H" + MacAddress.Substring(10, 2))

        i += 6

    Next

    udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length, myAddress, 9)
End Sub
End Class
```

That is it. Then all you do is change your IP and MAC to suit your needs. Or if you need, you can add in text boxes for different inputs.